# Golang JSON Marshal/Unmarshal on struct containing byte arrays

Tags: json, go

I have a struct with various attributes that are byte arrays.  For each, I generate some random bytes and I try to marshal the struct.  However I can't seem to successfully unmarshal the struct.  I suspect this may be due to how I am generating random bytes but I'm not sure how to pinpoint the issue here.

Playground:
https://play.golang.org/p/alCsspELN4

Comment: Your struct fields are unexported.

Comment: @TimCooper it's in a single `main` package though.

Comment: It doesn't matter. For the reflection library to properly work with the fields they must be exported, and `encoding/json` uses reflection.

Comment: Ah I see, did a quick lookup on that and it seems to have fixed my issue -- couldn't find the linked question in any of my google queries earlier.  Thanks!

Comment: @TimCooper yes my bad.